# Mapping key using xmodmap changes multiple keys

Tags: xmodmap, xpra

I am running Ubuntu server 16.04. Not sure if this matters, but I am forwarding the screen to a browser using [XPRA](http://xpra.org/).

All works reasonably well except for a few pesky key combinations. I am using a GB keyboard where between the SHIFT and Z keys there is a key with `backslash` and `bar` (pipe), let's call this the 'bar key'. At the top left of the keyboard there is a key with a `grave` and `notsign`, let's call this the 'grave key'.

These keys all work fine in the client OS as well as when using SSH to the server. However, the moment I use them in any of the forwarded applications, e.g. xterm, they display incorrect characters.

The 'bar key' displays '\' (correct) and '¬' (incorrect, this should be '|').

The 'grave key' displays the grave '`' (correct) and notsign '¬' (correct)

So I tried the usual `xev` & `xmodmap` combination to figure out the keycodes and map them.

When I run xev I get the following output for the 'bar key'

```
backslash (\): keycode 94 
bar (|): keycode 49
```

and the following for the 'grave key'

```
grave (`): keycode 49 
notsign (¬): keycode 49
```

Looks like there is a lot going on on keycode 49, it is mapped to multiple physical keys.

To check what position things map to, I executed the following

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = 1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

when I enter the various keys I get

```
\ = is still \ because we didn't remap 94
| = 2
` = 1
¬ = 2 (also 2 ... brilliant)
```

So how can I remap this if 2 characters map to the same keycode / position combination? (I have a couple of other ones to remap, e.g the @ key outputs Q, but let's get the first one going first)

Here is some additional diagnostic info

```
~$ setxkbmap -query
rules: evdev
mode: pc105
layout: gb

~$ localectl status
   System Locale: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
                  LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
       VC Keymap: n/a
      X11 Layout: gb
       X11 Model: pc101
```

Comment: You might look at articles on `showkey -s` to see if the key is giving different scancodes when in shift and `setkeycodes` for mapping scancodes to keycodes before they get to X11 through `/dev/input/event*` which you can see with `xinput --test-xi2`.